# CRUD Administración de Permisos por Usuario/Evento/Procesos

Tags: mariadb, permisos, crud

## Escenario:

Luego de hacer un desarrollo para un proyecto he detectado un problema en la arquitectura de la base de datos de permisos.

## Nota: es muy probable que digan que se basa en opiniones y agradecería que algún moderador ubique en el foro adecuado esta pregunta y en tal caso si es en ingles me indique para hacer la debida traducción.

Me solicitaron que el sistema desarrollado tuviera la capacidad de manejar permisos muy profundos a nivel de un crud:

Este crud cuenta con los botones o posibles acciones de:

```
Ver 
Aprobar 
Cancelar    
Crear   
Guardar 
Modificar   
Desactivar  
Borrar  
Consultar!  
Enviar a:   
Imprimir    
Importar    
Exportar
```

Este crud debe repetirse en cada proceso; en este caso actualmente van 120 procesos que representan como el 5% del total que se espera deben ser desarrollados

Actualmente el sistema cuenta con 200 usuarios

Para manejar los Permisos vs Eventos vs Procesos: cree una tabla por cada evento

Ejemplo de la tabla

```
nombre: perm_guardar
    Idkey   Usuario Proceso1    Proceso2    Proceso3    Proceso4    Proceso5    Proceso6 -> Proceso1000
    1       00001   1           0           1           1           0           1
    2       00002   0           0           1           1           0           1
    3       00003   1           0           1           1           0           1
    4       00004   0           0           0           0           0           1
```

Como podrán observar en la estructura de la tabla tengo 1002 columnas, donde almaceno el id del usuario en la segunda columna y las ultimas 1000 son espacios para 1000 procesos en cada una de estas columnas guardo 0 por defecto y luego si hay que asignarle el permiso le asigno un 1; como verán el problema es de escalabilidad ya que luego del proceso 1000 no tendré donde poner el permiso

Por que use esta estructura, pensé que seria mas fácil a la hora de manejar los permisos:

La lógica era hacer una consulta concatenar todas las columnas en un string y quedaría de la siguiente manera(un string con 1000 caracteres):

```
$_SESSION['PERM_GUARDAR']='00001111111000000100010000->1000';
```

Al momento de saber si el usuario tenía permiso para un botón especifico, solo era necesario saber la posición del proceso y revisar que valor tenia el string en esa posición determinada:

Lógica:
Proceso 120 = posición 120 ?: saber si es 0 o 1

Armado del string del Permiso:

```
$stmtpre = SELECT CONCAT(TPSave_1, TPSave_2, TPSave_3, TPSave_4, TPSave_5, TPSave_6, TPSave_7, TPSave_8, TPSave_9, TPSave_10 -> 1000) AS result FROM $PermName WHERE KeyIdT_User = '$KeyIdT_User'";
```

Como verán esto me limita a 1000 procesos(1000 columnas), la pregunta o problema es como puedo mejorar la escalabilidad a nivel de base de datos mariadb?

Comment: Hola Francisco **porque no lees lo definido en el [help] , específicamente [ask], para saber si las preguntas que realizas en realidad buscan opiniones o son demasiado amplias**. Como otra opción donde preguntar, porque no lo realizas en el [chat]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que ya tienes una tabla `usuarios` con sus respectivos ids únicos, yo añadiría una tabla `procesos`. Digamos

```
id | proceso
 1 | 'facturar'
 2 | 'cobrar'
 3 | 'editar cliente'
 4 | 'editar orden de trabajo'
 5 | 'etc'
```

Y luego una tabla `usuario_permiso` que relacione qué usuario tiene qué permiso (y en esta tabla, la tupla `usuario - permiso` es una llave única, porque un mismo usuario no puede tener dos veces el mismo permiso).

```
id | id_usuario |  id_permiso
 1 | 0001       |   1
 2 | 0001       |   2
 3 | 0002       |   1
 4 | 0002       |   3
 5 | 0003       |   4
```

Eso te dice que

- el usuario `0001` tiene permiso para facturar y cobrar.
- el usuario `0002` tiene permiso para facturar y editar cliente.
- el usuario `0003` sólo puede editar órdenes de trabajo

La ausencia de una tupla `usuario - permiso` en esta tabla de relación significa que el usuario no tiene ese permiso. No es necesario poner explícitamente que el usuario X no tiene el permiso Y. Cuando revocas un permiso, simplemente borrar la fila que asocia al usuario X con el permiso Y.

**EDIT**
Pensando un poco más tu caso, si tienes **X** clientes, **Y** procesos y para cada proceso **Z** acciones que definen tu crud, entonces normalizando eso podrías tener las tablas

**usuarios**

```
    id | nombre
 00001 | Pedro
 00002 | Juan
 00003 | Diego
 00004 | María
 00005 | Anita
```

**procesos**

```
id | proceso
 1 | Proceso1
 2 | Proceso2
 3 | Proceso3
 4 | Proceso4
```

**acciones** (Acciones sería tu custom CRUD)

```
id  |   accion
1   |   Ver
2   |   Aprobar
3   |   Cancelar
4   |   Crear
5   |   Guardar
6   |   Modificar
7   |   Desactivar
8   |   Borrar
9   |   Consultar!
10  |   Enviar a:
11  |   Imprimir
12  |   Importar
13  |   Exportar
```

Con lo cual tu tabla de relaciones (a.k.a. permisos) sería

**permisos**

```
id | id_usuario  |  id_proceso | id_accion
 1 |    00001    |      1      |  1
 2 |    00001    |      1      |  4
 2 |    00001    |      1      |  5
 2 |    00001    |      1      |  6
 3 |    00002    |      1      |  1
 4 |    00002    |      1      |  2
 3 |    00002    |      1      |  3
 4 |    00002    |      1      |  8
 5 |    00005    |      4      |  1
```

Esa tabla `permisos` te dice que

- El usuario 00001 (Pedro) tiene permisos para ejecutar las acciones 1 (Ver), 4 (Crear), 5 (Guardar) y 6 (Modificar) sobre el **Proceso1**.
- El usuario 00002 (Juan) tiene permisos para las acciones 1,2,3 y 8 (ver, aprobar, cancelar y borrar) sobre el **Proceso1**
- El usuario 00005 (Anita) sólo tiene permiso para la acción 1 (Ver) sobre el **Proceso4**

---

Si tu CRUD tiene 12 acciones (eventos), has levantado 120 procesos, y éstos representan el 5% de los procesos posibles, significa que en tu planteamiento tendrías una tabla por cada evento (12 tablas) y en cada una de ellas 2402 columnas.

Eso es muy ineficiente y en lo que te planteo, podría lograrse lo mismo  con una tabla de eventos (12 filas), una tabla de procesos (2400 filas) y una tabla de permisos (12 x 2400 x N usuarios). Incluso, si te es más cómodo, la tabla de permisos podría tener un campo extra que dijera si el permiso está otorgado (1) o denegado (0).

Tus queries cambiarían de la siguiente manera:

Actualmente, si quieres saber qué usuarios tienen permiso para **Guardar** el **Proceso1** harías

```
SELECT id_usuario FROM perm_guardar WHERE Proceso1 = 1;
```

En la estructura que te propongo harías

```
   SELECT id_usuario FROM permisos
   JOIN procesos ON procesos.id = permisos.id_proceso
   JOIN acciones on acciones.id = permisos.id_accion
   WHERE procesos.proceso = 'Proceso1'
     AND acciones.accion = 'Guardar';
```

Con esto podrías añadir un millón de procesos sin crear más columnas en tus 12 tablas, y añadir más acciones sin tener que crear nuevas tablas de un millón de columnas cada una.

Dicho sea de paso, al menos en `mysql` (no sé si aplica lo mismo a `mariadb`) hay un máximo de columnas en una tabla, que es de 4096. Eventualmente tu modelo de datos puede topar con ese límite.

Comment: No me funcionaria a nivel de ejemplo: facturar tiene un CRUD con los eventos descritos y cada uno de esos eventos tiene un permiso distinto.

Comment: Gracias igual veré si puedo implementar algo como lo describes.

Comment: Te puse una segunda sugerencia que tal vez se ajuste mejor a tu caso de uso. Sea como sea, necesitas normalizar. Mantener esa sábana te va a volver loco

Comment: muchas gracias por tu actualización la segunda sección es mucho mas interesante; normalmente si el usuario no tiene un permiso utilizaría la columnas adicional para manejar 0 y 1; tendré que hacer adecuaciones a nivel de código ya que estoy utilizando como veras un string para controlar los permisos y este se genera en la sesión ahora tendría que ver como manejarlo.